# Wordpress 3.8.1 wp_nav_menu walker that doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress

in an attempt to a custom menu in my brand new theme, I have embedded an array with some parameters as shown in the support page available at the URL http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

However, these values seems to be overridden or not to work properly.

This is the code I implemeneted

```
<?php 
    $defaults = array('container' => 'div', 'container_id' => 'menu', 'container_class' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>', 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu');
    wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); 
?>
```

whereas this is the output

```
<div id="menu" class="menu-main-container"><ul id="menu-main" class="menu">test</ul></div>
```

Although the container class is an empty string, the code rendered include something not expected.

As for the items_wrap, referring to the guide that says "If a numbered token is omitted from the format string, the related parameter is omitted from the menu markup.", I'd like to understand what I can do to avoid token 1 and 2 to be printed. 
I guess I have to go for a custom walker. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question ( the menu class ) .

You are not really using an empty string. By leaving the string empty you are actually using the default value :

From codex :

> $container_class
>       (string) (optional) The class that is applied to the container
>
> ```
>     Default: menu-{menu slug}-container
> ```

which is what you have in the code ...

```
class="menu-main-container">
```

as for the second question, to omit those tokens just put another value without those tokens or with specific parameters along the lines of ..

```
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="my_whatever_id" class="my_whatever_class">%3$s</ul>',
```

or

```
'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
```

or even a callback

```
 apply_filters("my_filter_menu_items_wrap",'<ul class="nav">%3$s</ul>'),
```

That being said, I am not quit sure what is the disturbance that the default class / values is creating for you .

Comment: Hi Obmerk. To answer to your last question, it's just me that I like a clean HTML code, and the default class were not that clean IMHO.

Comment: @AndreaMoro Ho capito. Just be aware that omitting those classes and Ids might render it difficult for others to target it in some situations ( like plugins or custom code ) . it is even more so when dealing with widgets and sidebars for example. Those parameters are there for a reason ..

Comment: That said, using the before and after, or simply removing some entirely the <li> element doesn't solve my issue as I keep seeing something like <li class="menu-item-list-28 menu-class-something .... How can I clean completely this bit adding just one class per menu item with no id whatsoever?

Comment: @AndreaMoro I do not understand if you want to remove the ID or the classes ? Both are possible, not advised though ..Maybe you should open a new question for it , and post a comment with link here And I would respond it .

Comment: Well I'd like to remove the long class name and ideally replace with my bit. The same for the ID. So if you can pass me details for both it would be appreciated.

Comment: @AndreaMoro Like I said.. post a new question and then a link here as comment so I can see it ..